# Text Field. Swift. Storyboard

Tags: swift, storyboard

У меня есть `TextField` на `ViewController`.  После нажатия кнопки на этом же `ViewController` - информация из `TextField` читается и переносится в код программы, где проверяется.
После этого я использую переход `segue` на `NavigationController`. На `ViewController`, который принадлежит `NavigationController` есть уже другой `TextField`, и когда я пытаюсь внести информацию в него - приложение падает.

Comment: пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на Русский язык или задайте его на [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Приведите код для воспроизведения